# How to find numbers in the puzzle square box

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I was trying to find answers for below diagram.I simplified with four equation
as

```
a+b = 25
c-d = 35
a+c = 50
b+d = 60
```

then I got

```
a+b+c-d+a+c+b+d = 170
2(a+b)+2c = 170
2*25 +2c = 170
c=60
```

but it causes a=-10 which is wrong as there is no negative number.

How to solve puzzle?

Comment: Yeah, just observed. Sorry!

Comment: It seems what I did is correct only.There must be negative numbers.I thought we can find answers without negative numbers.Thanks

Comment: Yep, you're right!

Answer (score 1):

Answer for a,b,c and d are :

> $a=-10$, $b=35$, $c=60$ and $d=25$

Reasoning

> Let these be eq 1,2,3 and 4 then
>
> ```
> a+b = 25 -(1)
> c-d =35 -(2)
> a+c = 50 -(3)
> b+d =60 - (4)
> ```
>
> ```
> Adding  (2) & (4) we get
> c-d =35
> b+d =60 
> -----------
> b+c=95 - (5)
> ------------
> ```
>
> ```
> Now let us add eq (1) & (3) we get
> a+b = 25
> a+c = 50
> ---------
> 2a+b+c=75 -- (6)
> ---------
> ```
>
> ```
> eq (5) can written as b=95-c putting this value in equation (6) it gives value of a=-10
> putting value of a in eq (1) we get--> b=35
> putting value of b in eq (4) we get -->d=25
> lastly putting value of a in eq (3) we get ---> c=60
> ```